# Excel Macro Auto Show/Hide Columns Based on Value in Drop Down List

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro in Excel 2016 that auto shows/hides columns based on a drop down contained in a different cell. The drop down (in cell "K7") is currently using Excel's data validation referencing a range of a few thousand cells (that are text) in a different sheet.

This is my current code (thanks to Busse!) which I know does not have the auto show/hide functionality to instantaneously show/hide dependent on what the user selects in cell "K7":

```
Sub Hide_Columns_Containing_Value()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("R3:GJU3").Cells
        If c.Value Range("K7").Value Then
            Columns(c.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You will want to have this code (after modification) in the 'Sheetx' (whichever sheet your dropdown menu is located in) and set it such that it runs every time a cell is updated on that sheet.

Comment: `If c.Value Range("K7").Value Then` what do you mean here?

Comment: @TimWilliams they most likely meant `If c.Value = Range("K7").Value Then`

Comment: What @E.Trauger is saying is that you need to use a [Worksheet_Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Worksheet_Change` event in your sheet. If you want to show only the columns whose value in row 3 match K7, you can simplify a bit (the `If` statement is not necessary).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim R, V
If Target.Address = ("$K$7") Then
    V = [K7].Value
    For Each R In Range("R3:GJU3")
        R.EntireColumn.Hidden = R.Value <> V
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Notice that to get a column range, you may write either `Columns(R.Column)` or `R.EntireColumn`.

---

If there may be errors in the R3:GJU3 range, then use this instead.
Here, if there is an error, the column is hidden, but it's possible to show it instead.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim R, V
If Target.Address = ("$K$7") Then
    V = [K7].Value
    For Each R In Range("R3:GJU3")
        If IsError(R.Value) Then
            R.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            R.EntireColumn.Hidden = R.Value <> V
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: wooo!!! this is working for me, however after I change selection each time I get this:

    Run-time error '13':
    Type mismatch

And this row gets highlighted on the debugger:
    R.EntireColumn.Hidden = R.Value <> V

Comment: @vash1422 What do you mean by "after I change selection"?

Comment: when I am interacting with the workbook as my user would, and I initiate a change to the drop down in cell K7, the workbook takes about 10 seconds to load, the columns show/hide correctly, but I still get the error prompt.

Comment: @vash1422 Ok, I may have found: if the row R3:GJU3 contains errors (like #N/A), there is indeed an error in the loop. Does it come from this in your workbook? If this is the case, it's possible to adapt the program.

Comment: "I suppose the cells R3:GJU3 only contain text, and text that is in the validation list?"  I think this might be the issue.  This macro is for a summary page (sheet1) which is pulling the validation list from another worksheet (sheet2) in which I have intentionally made the validation range longer to accommodate the users varying data size to copy/paste (up to 5000 rows).  It is all text, however R3:GJU3 is a transposed array in which the blank cells from sheet2 are showing as #NA.  Is there a way to accommodate for the #NA's to not spit the error?  Thanks so much!

Comment: you beat me to the punch -- how could it be adapted?

Comment: @vash1422 Done, see the answer.

Comment: done! works perfect, thanks for saving me hours of frustration!